# SQL Server parse XML namespace

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to parse the XML below in SQL Server and dealing with the nodes in the below:

```
<PrebillMarkup xmlns="clr-namespace:Xyz.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Xyz.Query" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">  
    <PrebillMarkup.NewValues>   
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative">Calls with P.</x:String>
    </PrebillMarkup.NewValues> 
    <PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>   
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative">Calls with P on confi agreement.</x:String>   
    </PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>
</PrebillMarkup>
```

I don't have any SQL yet from all of my research since I can't seem to find any namespaces that come close to what I'm trying to parse.  Intended output is:

```
Original Values | New Values
_________________________________________________
Call with P     | Calls with P on confi agreement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very similar to the @DavidBrowne-Microsoft solution, just performance optimized.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<PrebillMarkup xmlns="clr-namespace:Xyz.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Xyz.Query" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <PrebillMarkup.NewValues>
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative">Calls with P.</x:String>
    </PrebillMarkup.NewValues>
    <PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative">Calls with P on confi agreement.</x:String>
    </PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>
</PrebillMarkup>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'clr-namespace:Xyz.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Xyz.Query'
, 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' AS x)
SELECT c.value('(PrebillMarkup.NewValues/x:String/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Original Values]
    , c.value('(PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues/x:String/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [New Values]
FROM @xml.nodes('/PrebillMarkup') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------------+----------------------------------+
| Original Values |            New Values            |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+
| Calls with P.   | Calls with P on confi agreement. |
+-----------------+----------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an `with xmlnamespaces` declaration on the query.  eg

```
declare @doc xml = '
<PrebillMarkup xmlns="clr-namespace:Xyz.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Xyz.Query" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">  
    <PrebillMarkup.NewValues>   
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative">Calls with P.</x:String>
    </PrebillMarkup.NewValues> 
    <PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>   
        <x:String x:Key="Narrative">Calls with P on confi agreement.</x:String>   
    </PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues>
</PrebillMarkup>
';

with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' as x,
                    default 'clr-namespace:Xyz.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Xyz.Query')
select @doc.value('(/PrebillMarkup/PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues/x:String)[1]','nvarchar(50)') [Original Values],
       @doc.value('(/PrebillMarkup/PrebillMarkup.NewValues/x:String)[1]','nvarchar(50)') [New Values]
```

outputs

```
Original Values                                    New Values
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
Calls with P on confi agreement.                   Calls with P.

(1 row affected)
```

By convention you match the xmlnamespace aliases to the namespace aliases used in the xml doc, but it's not technically necessary.  This works too:

```
with xmlnamespaces ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' as foo,
                    'clr-namespace:Xyz.Query.ViewModels;assembly=Xyz.Query' as bar)
select @doc.value('(/bar:PrebillMarkup/bar:PrebillMarkup.OriginalValues/foo:String)[1]','nvarchar(50)') [Original Values],
       @doc.value('(/bar:PrebillMarkup/bar:PrebillMarkup.NewValues/foo:String)[1]','nvarchar(50)') [New Values]
```